# Timer runs automatically instead of on button click javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I am trying to create a timer that runs once a button has been clicked and then resets once another button has been clicked. however, the timer runs automatically as soon as the application is launched and doesn't reset back to 0. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Timer.js**

```
var sec = 0;

function pad(val)
{ 
    return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; 
}

interval = setInterval( function()
{
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=pad(++sec%60);
    document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/60,10));
}, 1000);

function clearTimer()
{
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

**User Scripts**

```
$(document).on("click", "#RunningTrackerBackBtn", function(evt)
{

    clearTimer();

});

    $(document).on("click", "#TrackerTest", function(evt)
{
     /*global activate_subpage */
     activate_subpage("#TrackerPage"); 
    setInterval();        
});
```

**index.html**

```
<span id="minutes">00 minutes </span>:<span id="seconds"> 00 seconds</span>
```

Comment: Well, you call `setInterval()` immediately when `Timer.js` is included, that's what starts the timer.

Comment: Tangential: this is an inaccurate way to track the time, you have no guarantee that the `setInterval()` handler is executed exactly once every 1000 milliseconds. Instead of incrementing a second counter, you should save a start time, and compare it to the time when you're updating the display. The handler should also probably run more often than once a second.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `setInterval` code inside a new function:

```
function startCounter() {
    interval = setInterval( function()
    {
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=pad(++sec%60);
        document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML=pad(parseInt(sec/60,10));
    }, 1000);
}
```

And that's what you should call when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example:

HTML:

```
<span id="minutes">00 minutes</span>:<span id="seconds">00 seconds</span>

<button id= "start">Start</button>
<button id= "stop" >Stop</button>
<button id= "clear" >Clear</button>
```

JS:

```
var sec = 0;
var interval;

function pad(val) { 
    return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; 
}

function showTime() {
      document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML= pad(sec++%60) + ' seconds';
      document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML= pad(parseInt(sec/60,10)) + ' minutes';
}

function start() {
  interval = setInterval( function() {
        showTime();
  }, 1000);
};

function clearTimer() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    sec = 0;
    showTime();
}

function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}
$("#start").on('click', function() {
        start();
});

$("#stop").on('click', function() {
        stopTimer();
});

$("#clear").on('click', function() {
        clearTimer();
});
```

Running in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5sauhj8d/8/

Comment: Where exactly is that relevant though? Those spans are just updated as the timer counts down with the time, and that's done correctly in the OP.